# connect mongoose in nextjs middleware

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, middleware

I'm trying to connect next.js app to mongodb via mongoose in _middeware file(./pages/_middleware.ts )
But I get this error on incoming requests:

error - (middleware)\node_modules\mongoose\dist\browser.umd.js (1242:0) @ 
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

How can I fix it?

Comment: Show us the place you are importing and using mongoose

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I have created _middleware.ts inside api directory. I trying to make mongoose connection there and getting exactly same error as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

+1 I have the same issue when trying to use in the middleware the instance created for mongoose so I don't have to connect it every time I make a request... but it seems this might not be **supported** **yet**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is not possible to use node api calls inside of NextJS middleware as this middleware is executed in the Edge runtime.  Mongoose is a Node.js api, hence why is doesn't work.

[Edge and Node.js Runtimes](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/switchable-runtime)